# How can I map Hive table into HBase?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, hiveql

I need to map Hive table into HBase.
My Hive table is composed of three columns-name string, degree string, major string

I don't know how fill into blank(??)

```
CREATE TABLE hbase_table(??, ??, ??, ...)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = "??")
TBLPROPERTIED ("hbase.table.name" = "hbase_table");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the following query:-

```
 CREATE TABLE hbase_table(key int,name string,degree string,major string)
    STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:val1,cf1:val2,cf1:val3")
    TBLPROPERTIED ("hbase.table.name" = "hbase_table");
```

Comment: After creating HBase table as shown in your answer, I performed "INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE hbase_table SELECT * FROM hive_table (Which is composed of three columns - name string, degree string, major string". It result in error like Table insclause-0 has 4 columns, but query has 3 columns. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Give some constant number in your hive query. For e.g select 100,name,degree,major from hive_table. .

Comment: I gave some constant num in HiveQL like select 200, name, degree, major.... Anyway, It launched a job...but.. It's never completed...It still 0%(I can see % because I use Amabari service)

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a table with one column family and it can have 3 columns inside the column family.
Please refer the Hbase manual for the table creation command.

Comment: Can you please give me a example?